# Javascript package import cannot find package

Tags: javascript, import, ecma

I am glad to share my first npm package [eulejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eulejs). Since I need to test it, I found that the command `npm link` bind locally the package on another NodeJS project. Great! HOWEVER, I was not able to import it as a package in this way. Sad...

I published the package and made a [minimal project](https://github.com/alloyha/experiments/tree/main/web/eulejs-MVP). The `src/index.js` code is below:

```
import euler from "eulejs";

const diagram = euler({
  a: [1, 2, 3],
  b: [2, 3, 4],
  c: [3, 4, 5],
  d: [3, 5, 6],
});

/* Euler dictionary:
 *   {
 *      'a,b': [2],
 *      'b,c': [4],
 *      'a,b,c,d': [3],
 *      'c,d': [5],
 *      'd': [6],
 *      'a': [1]
 *   }
 */
console.log(diagram);
```

For installation:

1. Create and go to folder with command `mkdir ~/eulejs-example && cd eulejs-example`;
2. Create a file `package.json` with content below:

```
{
  "name": "eulejs-example",
  "description": "Example for package eulejs",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./src/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Not implemented\""
  },
  "keywords": [
    "jest"
  ],
  "author": "brunolnetto",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "eulejs": "^1.0.2"
  }
}
```

3. Install dependencies with the command run `npm install`;
4. Run the command `npm start`.
5. A similar error log appears:

```
[nodemon] starting `node ./src/index.js`
node:internal/errors:484
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '/home/brunolnetto/github/alloyha/experiments/web/eulejs-MVP/node_modules/eulejs/' imported from /home/brunolnetto/github/alloyha/experiments/web/eulejs-MVP/src/index.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at legacyMainResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:235:9)
    at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:847:14)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:909:20)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1124:11)
    at nextResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:28)
    at ESMLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:841:30)
    at ESMLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:424:18)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:76:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:75:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

It would be very nice to have a feedback on how to solve such issue.

Comment: Can you add details (to the question itself using the "Edit" link), like how you installed your npm package, don't fear to add all the steps you done so we can reproduce them. You should also add the code of your minimal project (or at least the import line) because links can rot, your minimal project code can be changed and so it wouldn't be relevant to your question anymore

Comment: I did as you recommended me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'm not familiar with this way of installing so I can't answer you right now, I'l give it a look tomorrow if no answer is posted

Comment: Today is two days since you said about take a look at this issue. Would you check this out, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, whe're helping for free out here, and I have been really busy last days, good luck for your problem

Comment: Sure, no worries. I figure it out. Good luck for your solutions. ;-)